# Errors imposing boundary conditions weakly with DG

Tags: finite-element, pde, discontinuous-galerkin, deal.ii

I am using interior penalty discontinuous Galerkin to solve a simple Laplace problem:
\begin{align*}
\nabla u=0 
\end{align*}
with prescribed 0 and 1 Dirichlet boundary conditions on opposite edges of a unit square. The other edges have 0 Neumann.
[image]
You'll see above that I have an image of the solution and it's gradient on the right.

The exact solution should be linear and it's gradient should be a constant value which is what I would get with continuous Galerkin. But with DG this isn't the case. I am getting some pollution of my solution and it's gradient at the corner. This won't happen if I defined continuous boundary conditions.

I need to integrate on the edge to queue for forces but the corner elements are causing me problems. I am using an edited version of step 74 of dealii for this and I can't impose BCs strongly in DG.

Any hints or tips on how to circumvent this issue? Other formulations and ways to impose BCs?

Comment: How did you get the plot on the right? Maybe it's just a post processing problem

Comment: A more important question would be the scaling of the axis first.

Comment: Moreover, what is the polynomial degree in your calculation and how did you choose the penalties for the Inner- and the BC-sides? For accurate results, the penalties should be as high as possible, but less enough to prevent a bad condition number. Also be aware that DG does not even directly impose $C^0$ solutions, which makes the result in this particular case extremely sensitive on the penalties, especially with a high polynomial degree.

Comment: #bobinthebox The plot on the right is directly using the Paraview Gradient filter of the solution. I get the same looking solution if I were to use the in-built dealii functions 
@ConvexHull the gradients aren't too high. The gradient in the domain is at 1, and at the corners goes form 0.2 to 1.5. 
Polynomial degree=1, the penalties are the same ones used in dealii step 74.

Comment: Refining at the edges slowly fixes the issue. I'll do that. 
Should I keep this question still open?

Comment: @CuteCompute The values 0.2 to 1.5 are definitly to much off. These should lie at most in the range between $\nabla u = 1 +- \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ scales with the inverse of the choosen penalties.

Comment: Refining the mesh implicitly increases the penalties (according to deal.II). You may increase them by hand. What is your mesh resolution?

Comment: The red and blue contours in the corner are an element each. I think this was at 64x64 elements.

Comment: @CuteCompute Did you try to use a very large penalty as the one in the answer posted by ConvexHull?

Comment: Importantly, if you use polynomial degree 1, the exact solution is in the discrete solution space and the discrete solution needs to be exact. If it isn't, something is wrong.

Comment: @bobinthebox Large penalties aren't making a difference.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth same code with strongly imposed CG works as expected. The DG code isn't doing this. Should I take it to the dealii google group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it after help from the dealii user group. It was a coding error on my part.
Thank you all for your inputs

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with deal.II. However, to show that DG is able to reproduce
the constant gradient solution I will post some results with a different tool using IP. The penalty is about $\sigma\approx1\times10^8$, the polynomial degree is $P=1$.

**Edit**:

The solver is based on a "grad/div" or "strong-weak/weak" formulation. The system is assembled using the flux form and solved in primal form (applying the Schur complement). Using this approach all contributions in the system matrix from element-outside are set to zero using Neumann BC's. The matrix system is solved using direct LU.

---

**Coarse mesh: 2x2 elements**

[image: a]

---

**Medium mesh: 8x8 elements**

[image: b]

---

**Fine mesh: 32x32 elements**

[image]

---

Comment: Is there a term in the weak from associated with the zero Neumann BC?

Comment: @CuteCompute The solver is based on a "grad/div" or "strong-weak/weak" formulation. The system is assembled using the flux form and solved in primal form (applying the Schur complement). Using this approach all contributions in the system matrix from element-outside are set to zero using Neumann BC's. The matrix system is solved using direct LU.

Comment: Can you share a paper that best illustrates this formulation?

Comment: I think the methodology is quite standard.